# Firebase Auth: Suggested work flow for creating and updating user profiles: A way to check if a user is brand new?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, vuejs2, firebase-authentication

I have a blog app where users can sign up and post articles and comments. I need help figuring out a good app work flow for the following:

A new user signs up and enters his email address, password and a unique username that he would like to go by. The app checks the validity of the username and if it doesn't exist, it will create a new user document and a new username document:

**user profile document:**

[image]

**username document:**

[image]

After the username and user documents are created (batch write), I log out the user and send him an email verification email. He can't log into the site until he verifies his email. Once he does verify the email, he can then log into the site. I now get the currently signed-in user via the `onAuthStateChanged` observer like so:

**`~/plugins/auth.js`:**

```
  onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    if (user) {
      store.dispatch('onAuthStateChangedAction', user)
    } else {
      store.dispatch('logOutUser')
    }
  })
```

**and in the app's store, I have the `onAuthStateChangedAction` like so:**

```
  async onAuthStateChangedAction({ commit, dispatch }, authUser) {
    const { displayName, email, emailVerified, photoURL, providerData, uid } =
      authUser
    commit('SET_AUTH_USER', {
      displayName,
      email,
      emailVerified,
      photoURL,
      providerData,
      uid
    })
    await dispatch('getUserProfile', authUser)
  }
```

So I got the signed-in user, but what's a good way to set user profiles when user signs in for the first time? Some users are signing in for the first time and other users may already be existing users and don't need their user profiles recreated (I am trying to prevent writing to firestore if it's not necessary).

But, if he's already been fully signed in previously, no need to do that. I just want to grab his profile and move on.

Is there some kind of property I can add to the `user` document so I know that a user is brand new and hasn't fully signed-in yet?

My **`getUserProfile`** action:

```
  async getUserProfile({ commit, dispatch }, authUser) {
    
    // if user logging in to the first time, add new fields, but if already existing user, just grab his user profile 
updatedAt: serverTimestamp(),
emailVerified: authUser.emailVerified

  }
```

Perhaps there is a better way to approach this use case and something much simpler? Thanks for any comments or advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Users may already be existing users and don't need their user profiles recreated

You can check if their document has already been created. If not, add the document else proceed.

```js
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
  if (user) {
    if (!user.emailVerified) {
       // User has not verified the email yet
       // Force logout user
    }
    const {uid} = user
    const userDocRef = doc(db, "users", uid);
    const userDocSnap = await getDoc(userDocRef);
    if (userDocSnap.exists()) {
      // Profile document is already added
      if (userDocSnap.data().emailVerified) {
        // the user has probably logged in before
      } else {
        // The field is still false means it's first time after verifiying
        // Update doc
      }
    }  else {
      store.dispatch('onAuthStateChangedAction', user)
    }
  } else {
    store.dispatch('logOutUser')
  }
})
```

Other way would be to use `isNewUser` property from [`additionalUserInfo`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth#additionaluserinfo). But if you are using email-password auth then `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` method will always return `isNewUser` as `true` and `signInWithEmailAndPassword` will always return `false` as user is logged in when the account is created. So the next time they log in, they are no longer a new user.

Additionally, you can use security rules to make sure a document is created only if it is missing.

```js
match /users/{userID} {
    allow create: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userID && resource == null;
    allow update: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userID;
}
```